# SWT ScrolledComposite horizonal and vertical scroll bar disabled

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

When I run my code scroll bars coming as disabled. I want to enabled it with fixed size. I am referring to this [example](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/window/Snippet020CustomizedControlTooltips.java) and I have added ScrolledCompisite code in the creatContenyArea method. Appreciate suggestion on how to fix this thanks.

```
 @Override
 protected Composite createContentArea(Composite parent) {
     ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL
     | SWT.V_SCROLL);
     sc.setMinSize(100, 100);
     sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
     sc.setExpandVertical(true);
     sc.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));
     sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
     
     Composite comp = super.createContentArea(sc);
     comp.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));
     FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
     layout.marginWidth=5;
     parent.getShell().setLayout(layout);
     Link l = new Link(comp,SWT.NONE);
     l.setText(
             "This a custom tooltip you can: \n- pop up any control you want\n- define delays\n - ... \nGo and get Eclipse from <a>http://www.eclipse.org</a>");
     l.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));
     l.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
             openURL();
         }
     });
     sc.setContent(comp);
     return comp;
 }
```

Comment: `sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);` causes the scrollbars to always be displayed, even if they are not needed. And not needed scrollbars are shown as disabled.

Comment: Also note if you set the Background colour to COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND you also need to set the Foreground colour to COLOR_INFO_FOREGROUND otherwise you get unreadable text in dark mode.

Comment: @howlger The content which I want to display is huge if I don't set the scroll bar it is juts expanding and looks ugly

Comment: If you mean you want the tool tip window to have a fixed size you do that by setting the Shell size.

Comment: @greg-449, Updated the question, I tried to set shell size parent.getShell().setSize(200, 100); inside createContentArea in the first line still not working.

Comment: @greg-449 I added parent.getShell().setLayout(layout); it worked but some of my tooptip content go missing as the layout is fixed size. I want to have a fix layout with scroll bar enabled.

Comment: I fixed it. It seems I miss adding the scrolledComposite listener.

Comment: @Maana for further queries you can reach me through LinkedIn  https://www.linkedin.com/in/subashjanarthanan/